# How to add C to Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse

can anybody help with Eclipse plugins and some general advice ?

I use:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).
Build id: 20180917-1800.

That is on a Mac book pro running MacOS Catalina (10.15)

I would like to start learning C and i was thinking of using the Eclipse IDE i used for learning Java. 
As i read in similar questions like these i understand that there are two options:
One method would be using Oracle dedicated Eclipse CDT compiler and just install another Eclipse app.
This solution is good but involves two Eclipse apps.

The second method will be to download some plugins using "Install new software" or "The Eclipse marketplace".
For this solution i would like to ask which Plugins and\or Software i should install in the
one version that i use for Java ? (it is not clear what to install, not on Oracle help files and not in similar questions here).

Another question that comes to mind (as i read in other similar questions on C in Eclipse) is:
will using the same IDE for Java and C will cause problems of any sort or Eclipse is good to handle both ?

What i have already tried is using Xcode which work nice for me for C, i also checked CodeBlocks web page but as i can see there, there is no support for MacOS Catalina (not much support for Mac in general). In any case i like Eclipse and used to it and would like to use it for C too.
If there is any other idea or recommendation  for Coding with C on my system please share.

Thank you all in advance.